# Restructure code block so that Unused warning is eliminated

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-warnings

Having inherited a project from an Outsourced development company, I've been asked to modify the application and add some features.

Being a bit of a perfectionist (but still relatively new) I'm trying to eliminate Warnings from the Project when I compile.

I'm getting this error

Unused variable 'timer' at the end of a function

Which is setting a refresh button back to enabled after the timeout.

How can I rework this so that I don't get the unused (I can't comment it out, because it's actually doing what it's supposed to by resetting the state after the timer elapses)..

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    //lots of previous code
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(enableRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the assignment and have it read:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(enableRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Without the `NSTimer *timer =`.

Apparently the pointer to the timer object just isn't needed because it simply does what it is supposed to do right away. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you still need reference to that timer later in that method do:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    //lots of previous code
NSTimer *timer;
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(enableRefresh) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    //lots of other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always the fake operation:

```
(void)timer;
```

I used it a lot to avoid unused parameter warnings, to the point of making it a macro.